# GET POST Https Requests fail on my website (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx, https

I've been running a silly little website for around two years: [mtgpilot.com](https://mtgpilot.com/)

The site was running fine until a few certificates expired.  I decided to create a new AWS Lightsail instance and setup the site again.  I followed all of the same steps I used when I first created the site, except now I am getting a 20 second timeout whenever I try to make a post or get request to the server.

The stack uses Angular (code [here](https://github.com/lewiskeifer/MTG-Pilot-Frontend/blob/master/src/app/_service/authentication.service.ts#L11)) and Spring Boot (code [here](https://github.com/lewiskeifer/MTG-Pilot-Backend/blob/master/src/main/java/keifer/controller/LoginController.java)).  My nginx config is as follows:

```
# HTTP server

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.mtgpilot.com;

     location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then

        # as directory, then redirect to index(angular) if no file found.

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }

    # redirects both www and non-www to https

    return 301 https://mtgpilot.com$request_uri;

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

     location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then

        # as directory, then redirect to index(angular) if no file found.

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }

    # redirects both www and non-www to https

    return 301 https://mtgpilot.com$request_uri;

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
}

# HTTPS server

server {

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
   listen       443 ssl;
   server_name  localhost;

   if ($host != "mtgpilot.com") {

       return 301 https://mtgpilot.com$request_uri;

   }

   ssl_certificate      server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

   ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
   ssl_session_timeout  5m;

   ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

   include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

   include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
}


include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf";
```

I created my certificate using letsencrypt.  Nginx points to these based on [this guide](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress#complete-the-prerequisites-lets-encrypt-wordpress).  My backend is configured to point to this same certificate which I also added to the java keystore.

I have tried every possible combination of configurations I can think of.  My stack is a pretty standard use case, so there must be some relevant resources I can use.  I feel like I've thrown away a ton of hours of work all because some simple config is incorrect.

Even switching to http for the backend call fails with http failure response for 0 unknown error.

I also thought it might be a CORS error, but I had [fixed this issue before](https://github.com/lewiskeifer/MTG-Pilot-Backend/blob/master/src/main/java/keifer/configuration/CorsConfig.java).

Any help is appreciated.  The site is live now, and I have linked to all relevant code to allow reverse engineering.

Comment: have you checked the security group, make sure the ports are allowed

Answer (score 0):

Vilsad gave me an idea how to solve it.  Turns out it was not code related at all.  Just needed to allow port 8080 via the Amazon Lightsail UI configurations.